# What's the best way to run function/logic on Redux app start?

Tags: redux

The question is given, what's the best way to execute a function/logic on app start?

I thought there could be an action dispatched with `type` something like `APP_START` and a reducer will take care of the rest...

If that's a good approach, how to dispatch that action on app start? Shall I dispatch it from main app container's `componentDidMount`?

Comment: yes, `componentDidMount` is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David Tryon for confirming, It looks like that's the way to hook up on a redux app start: use main container's `componentDidMount`

To make it a bit nicer and abstract for modules, I created an app-level action called `START_APP` which is dispatched the place above. In a module-level middleware it is easy to look for this action and fire the module's own initialisation action. This way multiple modules can be initialised without touching app-level code.